# How do I collect multiple entries into a single label using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, dynamic, widget

I'm trying to create a tkinter program that allows for dynamically adding Entry fields using a button. I have that in place but now I am trying to store the user inputs as variables for however many entry boxes are added. Ideas?

For example if I hit the button 4 times and 4 Entry boxes are added I want to store those 4 user entries as 4 variables (or at least strings) for further use

Current code:

```
# add() adds multiple text boxes

all_unq = []
count = 0
def add():
    global count
    MAX_NUM = 15
    if count <= MAX_NUM:
        all_unq.append(tk.Entry(main)) # Create and append to list
        all_unq[-1].grid(row=14+count,column=1,`enter code here`pady=5) 
# Place the just created widget
        count += 1 # Increase the count by 1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You will need to keep track of the `Entry` widgets that are added in a list. You should then be able to `get()` the contents of each of them when you want to process it.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need some initial variables...

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
entries = []

createEntry = tk.Button(root, text="click me!")
createEntry.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=15)
```

Then, you will need a function to create the entry when the button is clicked...

```py
def makeEntry():
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    entry.grid(column=len(entries)+1, row=0, pady=3)

    entries.append(entry)
```

Finally, you wrap everything up by calling `root.mainloop` and binding the button to the mouse to make it responsive...

```py
createEntry.bind("<Button-1>", command=makeEntry)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! That I have already. My issue is being that the above code I posted creates a button that dynamically adds as many entry widgets as the user wants how can I .get() all the user inputs from those dynamically created entry boxes?

Comment: Jason: Both @Bryan Oakley and I have explained to you how to do that.

Comment: I have tried all of the above and the only thing that prints is an empty list. It has the exact number of entry boxes in the list, but no matter what I enter in the boxes, .get() is not retrieving any of the entered data like it should. Still open to ideas

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of entry widgets, just iterate over it. For example, here's how to print the value from each entry widget. Note that you'll need to declare `all_unq` as global if you want to do this in a separate function.

```
for entry in all_unq:
    print(entry.get())
```

If you want a list with all of the values, you can use a list comprehension:

```
all_values = [entry.get() for entry in all_unq]
```

Comment: Now just getting an empty list
all_unq = []
count = 0
def add():
    global count
    L = ' '
    if count <= 10:
        new_box = tk.Entry(main)
        all_unq.append(new_box) 
        all_unq[-1].grid(row=14+count,column=1,pady=5)
        L += str(tk.Entry(main).grid(row=14+count,column=1,pady=5))
        count += 1 
for x in range(1):
    unq_matrx = tk.Entry(main)
    unq_matrx.grid(row=x, column=1)
    all_unq.append(unq_matrx)
def printUniques():
    all_values = [unq_matrx.get() for entry in all_unq]
    tk.Label(main, text= (all_values)).grid(x, y)